# Number of chains of a given set.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S=\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ be a given set of size $n$, then we define  a *chain of size* $k$ as a collection of subsets $S_1,S_2,...,S_k$ of $S$ such that for all $i,j∈\{1,2,...,k\}$ where $i≠j$, either $S_i\subset S_j$ or $S_i⊃S_j$. The question is how  how to count the number of chains of subsets of $S$ of length $n-i, 1\leq i \leq n$.

Comment: For example, number of chains of length n is equal to n!.

Comment: If $S=\{1,2\}$, then there are $10$ chains of length $2$?

Comment: Can the $S_i$ be empty? Can they be equal?

Comment: **Hint:** Instead of trying to count chains of $S_1\subseteq S_2\subseteq \dots\subseteq S_k$, try counting **partitions** $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_k,A_{k+1}\}$ where $A_1=S_1,A_i=S_i\setminus S_{i-1}, A_{k+1}=S\setminus S_k$ or equivalently functions $f~:~\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to\{1,2,\dots,k+1\}$ which satisfy certain properties.  In the event that $S_i\neq \emptyset$ for any $i$ and $i\neq j$ implies $S_i\neq S_j$ (i.e. no to both of Arthur's questions) then the functions are almost onto ($k+1$ needn't have a preimage).  If you've seen how to count onto functions, the same technique can be applied here

Comment: If they can be empty and they can be equal (i.e. yes to both of Arthur's questions) then the functions don't have any special properties and can be counted normally (*but that would yield a much higher result than $n!$ for number of chains of length $n$*)